# METEOR Iron router redirect when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this onBeforeAction hook in which I check if the user is NOT logged in OR NOT in a specific role (in this case employer role) and then I redirect them to a specific page (called verification). I works good upon navigation to that page but when I'm already on the page and hit REFRESH it seems like he PASSES the IF condition and continues with `Router.go("verification");`

The code:

```
Router.route("/employer/profile", {
  name:"employerProfile",
  template:"employerProfile",
  layoutTemplate:'employerLayout',

    onBeforeAction:function(){

        var user = Meteor.userId();
        if(!user || !Roles.userIsInRole(user, ['employer'])) { // checking if the user satisfies this condition e.g. if its a "GUEST USER" than he can't access this route
              Router.go("verification");
        }
        else {
          this.next();
        }
        return true;

    },


});
```

Here is a quick VIDEO DEMO showcasing what happens:

http://screencast.com/t/BEgwpXwqvwt

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like on page refresh Meteor subscribes to Roles collection, but hasn't downloaded any data yet, so userIsInRole return false.

I think you either need to wait until Roles subscribtion is ready (and it isn't the best option) or redirect to verification page later, when subscription will be ready. I recommend to use server method for this check. Move your verification code inside server method an use it: Meteor.call('verifyUser',  function (error, result) { if (result === false) Router.go("verification"); } );

Comment: I thought it might be an "processing" problem or the order of code execution because sometimes everything works fine and sometimes this anomaly occurs. Do you have a suggestion how to implement this check?

Comment: Move your verification code inside server method an use it: Meteor.call('verifyUser',  function (error, result) { if (result === false) Router.go("verification"); } );